# converting mysql to the new mysqli API

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to convert my mysql command to fit the new standard of mysqli and I will post the scripts and then the questions. I already created the table in the database.

config.php:

```
$dbhost="databasehost";
$dbusername="username";
$dbpassword="password";
$dbname="databasename";

$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect) or die ("Could not connect to database");

?>
```

insert.php:

```
include("config.php");

if (isset($_POST[firstname]) && isset($_POST[lastname]) && isset($_POST[age])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
    mysql_query($sql, $connect); 
    header("Location: add.htm");
    // "1 record added";
}
else {
    echo "no record added";
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$connect))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

view.php:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
if ($sql) {
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo $results['FirstName'] . ', ' . $results['LastName'] . ', ' . $results['Age'] .     '<br/>';
    }
} else {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}


mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

- First, how do I modify the scripts to use the mysqli instead of mysql?
- Second, when using the above script, when I add something from the
  form it always add duplicate entry. How do I prevent that?
- Third, to prevent sql injection what can I add to the code? I know
  for php attach I can use "$firstname =
  trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['firstname'])));" Will that also
  cover sql injection since I am sanitizing the input?

Comment: Neither `strip_tags()` not `stripslashes()` are valid tools against SQL injection, not even in legacy mysql extension. Disable magic quotes and use prepared statements.

Comment: Read about prepared statements. If you are lucky someone here will rewrite your code for you, but that is not what this website is intended to do. Write your code and ask our help if something is not working

Comment: Thank you. Seems like i have some reading to catch up on. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

kindly read through the official manual for the migration :

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi

Comment: Sorry, I read through the website, and it lets you use a "tool" that transfers the code for you. That is not the way you should do it, learn how to do it yourself by reading about prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you. Seems like i have some reading to catch up on. Thanks everyone.

Comment: it is official in the sense that it was written by MySQL staff, and manual in the sense that as said in the text, the tool is only half the job. I hope that noone would just blindly use a tool without looking at the code generated!